# Matching Sizes to Font Family Failsafe in CSS

Tags: css

I have a page that is using a non-standard font and arial as a fail safe.  Does anyone know if there is a way to set the font-size conditionally to the font?

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: Calibri, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em, .9em, .9em;
    /* Where 1em would be for Calibri and .9 would be for arial and sans-serif */
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question but currently you can't do this until the 'font-size-adjust' property is more widely supported. It normalises fonts that have very different native sizes. This is the simplest definition and example I could find:

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_font_font-size-adjust.asp

I'd say there's no harm in using it even now and then it'll be ready when browser support improves.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use [font-size-adjust](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_font_font-size-adjust.asp). The problem is that it has poor support (IMHO).